# Webpack ошибка при компиляции Less

Tags: reactjs, webpack, less

Получаю вот эту ошибку на Windows 10. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
На Mac как все работает, но на win10 с следующеми настройками получаю ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 0):

Ваша ошибка говорит что у вас проблема с подключением шрифта через **LESS**.

То есть таким образом

```
@import (какой то шрифт)
```

подключить шрифты к проекту не получится

Подключите щрифт через `html` **(cdn)** и все будет работать.

Либо если не хотите через **cdn** загрузите дополнительно пакет npm `file-loader` и добавьте следующий код к настройке `webpack` и все.

```
{
     test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
     use: [{
           loader: 'file-loader',
           options: {
                name: '[name].[ext]',
                outputPath: 'fonts/'
            }
     }]
}
```

Comment: Я добавил это, но это не решает проблему. Даже если я просто уберу импорт, все равно ошибка: ERROR in ./src/app/less/main.less 1:5
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:5)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
> body {
|   margin: 0;
|   padding: 0;
 @ multi ./src/app/index.js ./src/app/less/main.less main[1]

Comment: @user334737 а может у вас проблема с less файлами.Вы загружали less-loader ?

Comment: да, package.json- "less": "^3.9.0",
    "less-loader": "^4.1.0",

Comment: разные версии также пробывал, но пока что безрезультатно

Comment: @user334737 посмотрите настройку вебпака для less вот тут думаю должно помочь https://gist.github.com/sakthig/d8f99c4a31ca511caa8067537bededcb